# How I get Raw param from URL in Controller

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters

I want my hash to be correctly filled in in my controller but my link contains special characters that are incorrectly passed into my controller:

```
localhost:51756/Account/ConfirmEmail?key=80d34666-f491-4fbd-821b-4a1e5608e710&hash=B4fcSyRuy/2j94sek8JMxr7+kDg=&newEmail=aGFuc3BvcHBlQGhvdG1haWwuY29t
```

the hash in my controller = B4fcSyRuy/2j94sek8JMxr7 kDg=

```
public ActionResult ConfirmEmail(string hash, string key, string newemail)
    {
         //do something.
    }
```

The '+' has been changed in ' '. 
Annyone have an idea to get the raw param from my url?

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do two things:

1. You correctly encode the + character to have ASP.NET decode it correctly. As the URL encoded version of the + character is %2B (see [link](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)), the link would become "...hash=B4fcSyRuy/2j94sek8JMxr7%2BkDg..."
2. You encode the hash back to its original format by using `Url.Encode`.

Answer (score 0):

All the query string parameter values in a URL need to be URL-encoded. You can use the `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)` method in C# or the `encodeURIComponent(str)` method in JavaScript to do that.

The URL look as follows:

`http://localhost:51756/Account/ConfirmEmail?key=80d34666-f491-4fbd-821b-4a1e5608e710&hash=2j94sek8JMxr7%2BkDg%3D&newEmail=aGFuc3BvcHBlQGhvdG1haWwuY29t`